# Multipath routing with linux kernel 4.19

Tags: multipath

I have the following two devices `tun-1` and `tun-2`. They have the same ip address `21.2.0.3` and the same gateway `21.2.0.1` (each gateway points to a different device/VM, they just happen to have the same IP). I am trying to set up a ECMP(equal cost multipath) so that the forwarded request can be sent out randomly from any of the `tun` devices.

The below command works in the kernel 4.4 with ip tool `iproute2-ss130716`, but it fails with `RTNETLINK answers` error in the kernel 4.19 with ip tool `iproute2-ss170501`.

```
$ip route add default \
    nexthop via 21.2.0.1 dev tun-1 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 21.2.0.1 dev tun-2 weight 1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

```
21.2.0.0/24 dev tun-1 proto kernel scope link src 21.2.0.3 
21.2.0.0/24 dev tun-2 proto kernel scope link src 21.2.0.3
```

I want to use kernel 4.19 so that I can use the [L4 hash](https://cumulusnetworks.com/blog/celebrating-ecmp-part-two/) for the ECMP setup.

I wonder what the problem it is, and how to fix it? Is it just the ip tool version issue or it is kernel issue?